# Command find/sed is not working inside a While Loop

Tags: sed, find, sh

I'm trying to replace some text inside a list of HTML files with find and sed inside a while loop that reads a .csv file.

my .sh script looks like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
INPUT=myfile.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS='|'
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }

replace_word(){
    find . -type f -readable -writable -name '*.html' -exec sed -i "s/>[ ]*$1[ ]*</>{% trans '$1' %}</g" {} \;
    echo "parsed $1"
}

while read text;
do
{
    arg="$text"
    replace_word $arg
}
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Even replace_word() is being called, the HTML files are not being modified though the text I want to replace is there.

PS: when I call the function outside the while loop with some text I want to replace, it works fine but clearly, only once.

**EDIT**
myfile.csv looks like this

```
"Abajo"
"Abortos"
"Abril"
"Acceder"
```

After running the script I want to replace some HTML tags from

```
<span id="btn-down" class="btn btn-xs set_function_btn">Abajo</span>
```

To

```
<span id="btn-down" class="btn btn-xs set_function_btn">{% trans 'Abajo' %}</span>
```

And so on with every word on myfile.csv

Comment: Does the find line work standalone?

Comment: @Yunnosch yes it does.

Comment: What does a typical input line look like? You're not quoting it when calling `replace_word`, which can lead to problems. Also, you don't have to assign it to `arg`, you can just call `replace_word "$text"` directly, no?

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes, I've tried `replace_word "$text"` too but still nothing happens

Comment: Can you show a representative excerpt of `myfile.csv` and what the desired output looks like?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I just edited my original question with the info you asked for.

Comment: That'll never match, because `Abajo` (in your HTML) is not the same as `"Abajo"` (in `myfile.csv`).

Comment: Yes, because you use `Abajo`. When you read the lines from your file, the contain double quotes, `"Abajo"`, and you don't have the string `"Abajo"` anywhere.

Comment: But you are running effectively, `sed -i "s/\"Abajo\"/stuff/"` which of course isn't matching.

Comment: But if I do e.g `text="Abajo"` and then call `replace_word "$text"` all this without any loop, it works fine. I'm really confused.

Comment: If you do `text="Abajo"`, the quotes are syntactical and are removed as part of the assignment. If you read them from the input file, they are literal. Try `echo "<$arg>"` and you'll see that you have literal double quotes.

Comment: It's true! how do I remove the quotes then? Directly from the file?

Comment: If you can control the creation of that file, you should make sure there are no quotes to begin with. If not, you can use parameter expansion: `while read text; do replace_word "${text//\"}"; done`

Comment: Why, by the way, are you setting `IFS` to `|`?

Comment: the `|` is setting like that because the sentence may have commas (,) within.